Center the button relative to the component if the button uses position: fixed
FirstPage.tsx
 export function FirstPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Sidebar />
      </div>

      <div className="w-[100vw]">
        <MainPage />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

And also code for MainPage.tsx
MainPage.tsx
 export function MainPage() {
  return (
    <div className="m-auto flex h-full w-[43vw] flex-col">
      <div>
        <SomeComponent1 />
      </div>

      <div>
        <SomeComponent2 />
      </div>

      <div>
        <SomeComponent3 />
      </div>

      <div>
        <SomeComponent4 />
      </div>

      <div className="flex h-[45px] items-start justify-center">
        <Button />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

The current behavior for MainPage is such that if all the content does not fit into the view (due to reducing the page height or applying zoom), then a scroll appears.
However, I would like the Button component to be always visible when the scroll appears. To do this, I added fixed and bottom-0 to className, that is, the className in the bottom div began to look like className="fixed bottom-0 flex h-[45px] items-start justify-center"
This way I got the desired result, but now the Button component is not horizontally centered relative to the MainPage component
Please tell me how I can ensure that the Button component is centered as before.
Perhaps you can advise me to implement my functionality without using fixed. I am open to advice and discussions

If you want to set the child component an absolute position relative to the parent try setting the parent div with relative (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/position)

You can achieve what you want without fixed positioning. Just use a wrapping div that holds your current flex container and the button, and make sure your internal flex container has grow and overflow-auto. Something like:
export function MainPage() {
  return (
    <div className="m-auto flex h-screen w-[43vw] flex-col">
      <div className="flex flex-col grow overflow-auto">
        <div>
          <SomeComponent1 />
        </div>

        <div>
          <SomeComponent2 />
        </div>

        <div>
          <SomeComponent3 />
        </div>

        <div>
          <SomeComponent4 />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="flex h-[45px] items-start justify-center">
        <Button />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Note I added h-screen to the outer container. h-full would suffice if the parent component FirstPage is given h-screen.
I created a Tailwind playground to illustrate my solution. Try remove some of the red boxes to verify the button stays at the bottom

Thank you, this is very original. But the thing is that vertical and horizontal scrolling appears within the components SomeComponent1 - SomeComponent4. And this is a very undesirable event. I basically found a solution to my problem by replacing fixed with sticky. But there is another problem. You can take a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/78310108/17122431

But I really like your solution, since I won’t have to solve additional problems. Perhaps you can tell me how you can get rid of unwanted horizontal and vertical scrolling in your solution

@Paul, without knowing how you implemented  SomeComponent1 , etc. it's hard to tell why scrolling occurs inside them

I tried to simulate it in tailwind playground. I added a parent div to the menu items and set the flex to 1.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/MjLminsTVJ

Thank you very much for trying to help me with my problem, but this is not a working option either. You can see this for yourself

I don't use tailwind, but I think it shouldn't be difficult to solve. I tried to modify the playground once again, maybe that will help
https://play.tailwindcss.com/QUkncfzSx5
